# ZAP frequency of definition updates and relevance to NIST if any

Tags: zap

Does anyone know the answer to the following questions regarding ZAP?

1) How often are the ZAP definitions updated?
2) Are there any relevance between ZAP and NIST security compliance requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As the core team feels there's something worth releasing. (Which generally depends on impact of changes/additions/removals and community contribution.) [There is no set frequency.]
2. It depends which NIST guide(s)/doc(s) you're referring to. NIST has a non-trivial set of publications.